# How to create a shared folder between Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, permissions, windows, directory, shared-folders

How to create a shared folder between Linux and Windows?
If possible, do not use additional applications. If it's not possible, please tell me the app that can be used.

These are my previous steps:

1. My Windows has a folder in `\\IP\Data_Folder\01_share_folder` and the status of this folder is already shared.
2. My Linux has a folder in `/home/user_name/01_share_folder/` where the owner is root.
3. In the Linux terminal, I log in as root and type the following command:

   ```bsh
   mount -t cifs //IP/Data_Folder/01_share_folder /home/user_name/01_share_folder/ -o username='username',password='password'
   ```
4. Linux successfully reads the folder and files on Windows, but when I create or upload a file from Linux, I get a "permission denied" error.
5. Then I checked the permission code, and it turned out to be `775`, then I tried to change it:

   ```bsh
   chmod -R 777 /home/username/01_share_folder/
   ```
6. But not working and it's still `775`.

I Use MobaXterm to access Linux.

Linux Version:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
```

My Windows Version :

```
Windows Server 2019.
```

Comment: google "mount cifs example":
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/

Comment: It's Work Thanks